# Printing only nth number of prime sequence, python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program in python that can either print 1 through nth numbers of the prime number sequence, or print just the nth number of the prime number sequence.  Here is the code.

```
import math

P = 2
X = raw_input('Choose a number: ')
Y = 1

def prime(P, Y):
    Choice = raw_input('Select 1 to print X numbers of the Prime sequence. \nSelect 2 to print the Xth number in the Prime sequence.  \nWhat is your choice: ') 

    if Choice == "1":
        while Y <= int(X):
            isprime = True
            for x in range(2, int(P) - 1):
                if P % x == 0: 
                    isprime = False
                    break
            if isprime:
                print P
                Y += 1
            P += 1
    elif Choice == "2":

prime(P, Y)
```

Basically, i have the first part down, so that it prints 1 through nth numbers of the prime sequence.  However, I'm quite lost on how to make it calculate just the nth prime, where the nth prime is the given through raw input.  It must be possible to do this in python, however, how would it be done, and what would be the best way to do so, without having to add too many new variables that i don't have here, (though i would be fine doing so).  Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition so that if *either* the user wants to print all numbers, *or* you have reached the final prime number of the sequence, the number will be printed. (I have also replaced some of the variable names with more descriptive ones, and altered it so that the function is passed the `number_of_primes` as its only parameter, which would seem to make more sense.)

```
def print_primes(X):
    choice = raw_input('Select 1 to print X numbers of the Prime sequence. \nSelect 2 to print the Xth number in the Prime sequence.  \nWhat is your choice: ') 
    count = 1
    n = 2
    while count <= X:
        is_prime = True
        for i in range(2, int(n) - 1):
            if n % i == 0: 
                is_prime = False
                break
        if is_prime:
            if choice == "1" or count == X:
                print n
            count += 1
        n += 1

number_of_primes = int(raw_input('Choose a number: '))
print_primes(number_of_primes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just only print if it's the Yth number:

```
if isprime:
    Y += 1
    if Y == X:
        print P
```

Comment: Really, you have to do the loop either way and count up to the Xth prime number no matter what they chose; I would just move the `if` inside the loop and only print each result if either they picked 1 or X == Y.